# datastax solr search RELOAD resets schema.xml

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

I've encountered a curious behavior in DSE search. If a core is created via generateResources=true and later on the schema.xml is updated via POST to /ks.table/admin/file?schema.xml it would be reverted to its initial version if /ks.table/admin/cores?action=RELOAD is called.

```
dsetool create_core ks.tablename generateResources=true
```

schema.xml in solr now includes all fields as indexed="true"

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/resource/ks.tablename//schema.xml --data-binary @edited_schema.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

schema.xml in solr is now updated with selected fields set as indexed="false"

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&name=ks.tablename
```

schema.xml in solr is now reverted to all fields being indexed="true"

Is this an intended behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue, can you upgrade to the latest DSE and try again?

I believe its fixed.

Comment: I believe I have the latest version: Cassandra 2.0.11.83 | DSE 4.6.0. Do you know what's the cause? maybe I can just work around it. (nm, I see 4.6.5 is the latest, I'd try that and report if it's working)

Comment: I am now getting an inexplicit error: "Multi-valued field record_id should be mapped to either List or Set types, found: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType." The field is not marked as MultiValued. It's using the generated schema.xml and the only thing changed is indexed="false". error occurs on RELOAD

Comment: disregard. is was due to version not being present in the updated schema.xml